# Unexpected kinks in mesh

Tags: normals, subdivision-surface

[image]

I'm getting these weird kinks (see top and bottom hole here) and can't figure out why. I can't see any duplicate vertexes causing issues, or any issues with normals. Any ideas welcomed at this point... Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its caused by the bevel and subdivision modifier not having enough supporting geometry. Create a `Loop Cut` like so near the edge

[image]

Comment: Thanks a-python-script — that's worked, really appreciate you taking a look, didn't realise this would cause an issue — thank you